# Failing to see how ambassador pattern enhances modularity / simplicty of container architecture in Docker

Tags: docker

I fail to see how implementing the ambassador pattern would help us simplify / modularize the design of our container architecture.

Let's say that I have a database container `db` on host A and is used by a program `db-client` which sits on host B, which are connected via ambassador containers `db-ambassador` and `db-foreign-ambassador` over a network:

```
[host A (db) --> (db-ambassador)] <- ... -> [host B (db-forgn-ambsdr) --> (db-client)]
```

Connections between containers in the same machine, e.g. `db` to `db-ambassador`, and `db-foreign-ambassador` to `db-client` are done via Docker's `--link` parameter while `db-ambassador` and `db-foreign-ambassador` talks over the network.

But , `--link` is just a fancy way of inserting ip addresses, ports and other info from one container to another. When a container fails, the other container which is linked to it does not get notified, nor will it know the new IP address of the crashing container when it restarts. In short, if a container which is linked to another went dead, the link is also dead.

To consider my example, lets say that `db` crashed and restarts, thus get assigned to a different IP. `db-ambassador` would have to be restarted too, in order to update the link between them... Except you shouldn't. If `db-ambassador` is restarted, the IP would have changed too, and `foreign-db-ambassador` won't know where to reach it at the new IP address.

Quoting [an article](https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) in the Docker's docs about the ambassador pattern,

> When you need to rewire your consumer to talk to a different Redis
>   server, you can just restart the redis-ambassador container that the
>   consumer is connected to.
>
> This pattern also allows you to transparently move the Redis server to
>   a different docker host from the consumer.

it seems like this is exactly the problem it is trying to solve. Which, as far as my understanding goes, it totally didn't. Not if you consider `--link` is only useful as long as the linked container doesn't crash. The option to start a crashing node on its previous IP would have been a good workaround [if supported](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4952), at least for a small/medium sized architecture.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This open issue looks like what you want: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3155

Comment: very surprised to find such inaccurate and misleading information. I think you absolutly right. Ambassador pattern is completely worthless right now in my opinion. I'm not thrilled about the fact that you need to push your data via another container anyway, adding another possible point of failure. I hope docker's [major networking rewrite](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9983) will solve these issues.

Answer (score 6):

Jérôme had some good slides (11-33) on how ambassadors are better than other ways of service discovery (i.e. DNS, key-value stores, bind-mount config file, etc.) in his [slide deck on "Shipping Applications to Production in Containers with Docker"](http://slideshare.net/jpetazzo/shipping-applications-to-production-in-containers-with-docker). He also has some suggestions for how to solve the problem I think you are mentioning, especially [Docker Grand Ambassador](https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador) looks promising.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that deck. I'd like to find a video of it. I'm still not comfortable with running a proxy on each service provider and each service consumer, just because "DNS is hard". If you are on AWS, you can manipulate DNS with their API. That's what I do here https://github.com/RichardBronosky/aws-ecs-service-discovery

Comment: Warning, I just created that project last night and am yet to push the docs out. This comment will self destruct when that changes.