# ambassador pattern vs network alias pattern in docker

Tags: docker, service-discovery

For service discovery purpose, the ambassador pattern is recommended. However, like the OP for this stackoverflow question [Failing to see how ambassador pattern enhances modularity / simplicty of container architecture in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604734/failing-to-see-how-ambassador-pattern-enhances-modularity-simplicty-of-contain), I also failed to see the benefit of the ambassador pattern since all "-link"s are embedded into a container during `compose-up`
On the other hand, I just noticed these `network` and `alias` parameters for `docker-compose`, which seems to serve the purpose of service discovery. That is, if one of the container, say a DB container, goes down, one just need to restart that container and the other containers should be able to find it again since they are in the same network and it is identified with the same alias.

So, the questions is, should I use the network alias pattern over the ambassador pattern?