# What is the concept of Ambassador in distributed systems?

Tags: docker, architecture, cluster-computing, microservices, docker-swarm

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what is the architectural concept of an Ambassador in cluster computing? What are the benefits of implementing it in a microservice architecture patterns?

I've been studying docker and docker-swarm lately and I've been seen this term mentioned repeatedly across articles or repos. For example in [this amazing project](https://github.com/openstf/stf), they have a repository called [docker-ambasssador](https://github.com/openstf/docker-ambassador). Or this other project called [ctlc-docker-ambassador](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/ctlc-docker-ambassador).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604734/failing-to-see-how-ambassador-pattern-enhances-modularity-simplicty-of-contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits of Microservices in general is the ability to switch out underlying component pieces without the rest of the app/ecosystem having awareness of a change. The ambassador pattern allows for pieces to move and change while consuming code continues to connect to a single location. One of the links you provided had a great explanation/example:

> Rather than hardcoding network links between a service consumer and
>   provider, Docker encourages service portability, for example instead
>   of:
>
> (consumer) --> (redis) Requiring you to restart the consumer to attach
>   it to a different redis service, you can add ambassadors:
>
> (consumer) --> (redis-ambassador) --> (redis) Or
>
> (consumer) --> (redis-ambassador) ---network---> (redis-ambassador)
>   --> (redis) When you need to rewire your consumer to talk to a different Redis server, you can just restart the redis-ambassador
>   container that the consumer is connected to.

In this instance the underlying component (redis) can be moved or updated without the code that uses redis knowing. It would even allow one to switch from redis to another kv store if the code were a bit more clever.

Comment: But what's stopping you from having to hardcode port mapping in the redis-ambassador? I mean, isn't it just transferring the problem to another node in your distributed architecture?

Comment: Along with simply knowing where the underlying service is located, an ambassador node can be "smart", by which I mean it can direct traffic based on incoming requests. Say you had several redis nodes used for different purposes (cache, metadata,etc). The consuming clients could all talk to the one ambassador, which could intelligently manage requests and direct traffic to the proper final destination. Essentially becomes a smart load balancer at that point. Again not the only use for a complicated and flexible tool.